# How to print out the first and last 1000 lines using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, prettify

I am trying to print out the first and last 1000 lines using "prettify' from BeautifulSoup.  I have downloaded Kafka's The Metamorphosis to my hard drive and I've successfully created a BeautifulSoup object:

Due to captcha issues with the Gutenberg site, I saved a copy of the document on my hard drive.

```
page = open('meta.htm', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
```

How do I use `soup.prettify()` to print out the first and last 1000 lines of the document?

Answer (score 1):

Just *slice* them:

```
result = soup.prettify().splitlines()
print('\n'.join(result[:1000] + result[-1000:]))
```

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks!  How would I need to change this code if I just wanted to print out the first 1000 characters instead of the first 1000 lines of the document?

Comment: @James sure, just do the `print('\n'.join(result[:1000]))` for the first 1000 and `print('\n'.join(result[-1000:]))` for the last 1000.